# From a varchar column extract the last two digit seperated by '-'

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Dataframe like below

```
COURSE_KEY.           
INC-AAB-WW-123456    
INC-AAB-NL-104514
```

I need to fetch the numerical digit and the code before that. so that the data looks like below

```
COURSE_KEY
WW-123456
NL-104514
```

Comment: re.findall("-(\w+?-\d+)", x), apply to dataframe

Comment: Something like `df['COURSE_KEY.'] = df['COURSE_KEY.'].str.split('-', n = 2).str[-1]` may work?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your output easily by using `regex` pattern `(\w+-\d+)$`

- `\w+` any number of letters or digits.
- `\d+` any number of digits
- `$` end of line

```
df.COURSE_KEY.str.extract(r"(\w+-\d+)$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming df is your dataframe, you can use extract function to get the required string:

check below code

```
regex = "([A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{5})"
df['new'] = df['COURSE_KEY'].str.extract(regex)
print(df)
```